# How to stop an user from clicking on a link again when the ajax call is unfinished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onclick

I have a link, on the click i have done some javascript code and ajax on it, but the problem is when user click multi times without completing previous process, it will execute all click, i want to stop click until the previous process completed,

Comment: You can use validation for this

Comment: what kind of validation??

Comment: SO is not about what you want and we do it for you. It's about what you have tried and failed and we try to point out your mistake.

Comment: @marekful  dude if you do not know about it, its okay, you do not need to answer every question. i have got the solution

Comment: The question is reasonable and explains the problem appropriately. If the possible solution is unknown how can a developer code for it? The comment by @marekful is unappreciated.

Comment: Dudes, there are rules on how to ask on SO. This question disqualifies. I do know the solution but not willing to provide full solution to a low quality question. Learn how to create a good question that will attract smart people (that you are in need of).

Comment: @marekful There is no such thing as a "low quality question". All questions have answers.

Comment: @guest271314, You can think that. It's a democracy...

Comment: Also, by providing an answer with full solution and code to question that didn't demonstrate any attempt to solve a problem, you are encouraging people to do just that: expect other SO users to write code for them. Not good for SO.

Comment: @marekful I have try my best to explain my problem, and that is a problem i have face, If you understand my problem you can answer if not then leave it, Please do not put it on you. I appreciate that you want to maintain a slandered, but the issue was not with code. problem with execution. hop you understand, i got my solution, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.one()` and re-attach the event at `.then()` when asynchronous tasks have completed

```
function request() {  
  return $.ajax()
}

function handleClick(e) {
  request.then(function() {
    $(e.target).one("click", handleClick)
  }, function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       console.error(errorThrown)
  })
}

$("p").one("click", handleClick);
```

Answer (score 0):

what have you already tried?

first thing, that comes to my mind would be, create a global var, that defines the status of your on click process. per default, it should be false.

when starting your on click event, set it to true. at the end of your on click event, set it to false again.

then just put the whole on click thingie within an if statement, so it only gets executed when the bool you defined is false...